# Location of the .so files

Tags: filesystem, deb

I am trying to install deb package which contains `.h`, `.so` and `.a` files. After installing the deb package I am unable to find the installed location.

I checked `/usr/lib`, `/usr/local/lib` and `/lib`. I am supposed to install the `.so` and `.a` files in `/usr/lib` from deb package. To solve my problem, I copied the `.a` files from the extracted `.deb` to `/usr/lib` but the  `.so` files are not copying. Please help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Check out `apt-file`.

```
apt-file search horst.so
```

See [documentation at wiki.debian.org](https://wiki.debian.org/apt-file)

Comment: apt-file is not supported in newer version of debian/ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

To find which files were installed by a package, use `dpkg -L`:

```
dpkg -L $package
```

if you have the package as a .deb file locally, you can run `dpkg` on it:

```
 dpkg --contents $package.deb
```

So you can find where .so file is located

Comment: In software center it shows deb package is installed and in  terminal its showing "dpkg-query: package 'libgmt-dev_4.5.12-1_amd64' is not installed".

Comment: try **dpkg -L libgmt-dev**

Comment: There are in "/."  "/usr".  Why?  I need these files during installation  of another application in /usr/lib and some other locations. How to unhide these files and after unhiding those will come to the required locations?

Comment: Sorry, but I did not understand...the ouptut of the command shows you where each file is copied, btw the .a and .so files are under /usr/lib as you can see

Comment: Command shows as follows

Comment: /.
/usr
/usr/include
/usr/include/gmt
/usr/include/gmt/gmt_math.h
/usr/include/gmt/gmt_boundcond.h
/usr/include/gmt/gmt_common.h
/usr/include/gmt/gmt_symbol.h
/usr/include/gmt/gmt_calclock.h
/usr/include/gmt/gmt_contour.h
/usr/include/gmt/gmt_grd.h
/usr/include/gmt/gmt_project.h
/usr/include/gmt/gmt_mgg.h
/usr/include/gmt/mgd77_functions.h
/usr/include/gmt/gmt_notposix.h
/usr/include/gmt/mgd77_recalc.h

Comment: i am asking why these files in hidden directory that is "/.".

Comment: "/." is not an hidden directory... it is the base directory, aka "root" ... but in the output you don't have .so and .a files? just .h?

Comment: sorry I copied only few because of space issue. Again sorry to bug you, I checked modification date of the above mentioned installed files,  it is showing 2014 is the last modification date.

Comment: it is correct. as root run **stat /usr/lib/libmgd77.so** you will see modification date 2014 but change date is set to today (if you installed today the package)

Comment: If you are still willing to help me. I will tell what i am doing in elaborate sense.

Comment: I'm here, go on :)

Comment: I am installing a package called shana for my research work. Which inturn needed two more packages gmt and netcdf. I have instructions  to perform installation in steps. I successfully completed first two steps and now I am in 3rd. Third states like this "if the problem is with -ld returned status then few of the library files are not found in /usr/lib.
Give ld -lspl –verbose. This shows the particular place and the particular file that is not found. To rectify this, install rpm_package. It has all library files. “libgmt-devel-4.5.9-3.mga4.i586.tar.gz”.  These files are to be put in /usr/lib)"

Comment: so I d status is "error: ld returned 1 exit status"

Comment: I tried installing rpm package but I didn't succeed. Then one person in this site told me that deb package is available why are installing rmp. After that i downloaded deb package and I installed. Now after all this process I am not able find new library files stated above in the required locations. Still error is same.

Comment: difficult to say... maybe some libs are not in the system lib path... try using **sudo ldconfig**  if you already installed shana you can try to look the executable dependencies : **ldd <filename>**